# Best Practice CSS for complex site

Tags: css

I working on a right way to conduct the styling for a rather big website project, as I get usually stuck half-way, when the complexity increases. I already read quite some literature and found a lot of useful tips on the Internet, e.g. "use meaningful class names", and the like.

However, most sources are concerned with the actual working principle of CSS which are illustrated by rather short code examples. What I am actually looking for is a guide describing the styling of a website from start to end, including possible naming conventions, class management, file management and the like. Really great would also be a code example of medium-sized, or big site.

I am also grateful for any reference to books, magazines, articles and the like.

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-css-best-practices-for-beginners--net-6741 nice tutorial

Answer (score 0):

As I am not aware of any reference to book, I just follow basic things which makes my work quite smooth. Yes meaningful class names are must with that Try following the below which might help you

- Keep the code clean and neat which is indenting the code before you wrap up for the day
- Divide your css into part (Place the code of header and footer in one files Ex:base.css and the body part in another css Ex:main.css)